# h264 library for iphone

Tags: iphone, h.264

I am making a project In which I want to use h264 library ,

But anywhere I am not able to find the library or any sample which I can use as a reference .

can anyone please suggest me where i can find this?

p.s. I am using this for Iphone

Answer (score -1):

Probably you mean **х264**, the opensource library for decoding h.264/MPEG4-AVC content. Check it's [homepage](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html).

A useful example would be the source code for the VLC player for iPhone available [here](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html).

Comment: Hey ...VLC is using third party library or something and has been removed from the store .. see http://www.tuaw.com/2011/01/09/the-gpl-the-app-store-and-you/ ... and basically I want to compress the video without losing the quality .. can you tell me what to do?